# An idea to improve and help others

Tags: discussion

First of all - it's not a question, I'm not sure if I can make posts like this here (forgive me if I'm not supposed to) but let me explain. What I've been thinking recently is that we have so many chess-players or enthusiasts here. Most of us play chess online, a lot of people are asking for advices, analysis etc. Wouldn't it be great to create some kind of group @ one of chess platforms? We could organize weekly tournaments, analyze games live on chessboards, lots of stuff. Firstly chess.com came to my mind because many people are reffering to that site, it's mentioned frequently. What do you guys think? Would you mind creating new accounts with prefix like stack_? I think that we can spin it, we may grow fast and make it useful and helpful. Waiting for your calls!

Cheers!

p.s. I've just created my account called: stack_Justp0 . Feel free to add me, anyone!

Comment: I find this is a nice idea, but I would rather make a private group and let people in only if they have a chess SE account or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea does make sense. Yet, Chess StackExchange is more about asking and answering here on this site, not on other sites. Thus, a user on Chess SE can create a profile on an online blitz site and then link to the Chess SE site from their profile. That is already more than enough to help others. A question posted on Chess SE has a very high chance of getting a decent answer. Thus, the best thing we can do is to refer others to post their questions here, if they want their questions to be answered by Chess SE users.