# How about a chess program in the chat rooms?

Tags: feature-request, chat

I was just wondering why this site doesn't have a chess program in the chat rooms, so users from around the network could come in and play?

Comment: Why should we? Why not just goto chess.com, lichess?

Comment: @SmallChess Why not in Chess.SE as well? :)

Comment: Similar to https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/353/1108 where a user asked to create a team on chess.com.

Answer (score 4):

I can think of three reasons why:

1. Stack Exchange's primary purpose is to be a network of *Q&A* sites. All features, including chat, *support* this purpose. I don't see how adding a playing arena would be beneficial to this, except maybe to enlarge our audience.
2. The Chess SE chat isn't really active at the moment. Even if this would be implemented, there's no guarantee that people will actually use it instead of the thousands of other chess playing sites on the Internet.
3. The Stack Exchange developer team is *very* busy. Until recently, they didn't even have time to [properly maintain the Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272419/295232), which is quite a thing in the mobile-first world we're living in now. Chess SE is a *small* community, and we should count ourselves lucky that we have one feature specially developed for us (the [replayer](/questions/tagged/replayer)).

Comment: For the first point, I think by playing here, many users will be active here and they may ask questions as well. This will _increase number of questions per day_ and more chances to _graduate_ our Chess Beta. (As you can see our site is close to Graduation criteria. Just number of questions is lagging).